# Python Issue - Map and Classes - Beginner

Tags: python, class, dictionary, python-2.7

I'm attempting to use Map to reference a class function, but am having difficulty with formatting/ordering. I have heard that using map is sort of obsolete so I am definitely open to alternative solutions (for loops?) Thanks in advance.

```
lognames =  [ "C:\Users\makker1\Desktop\logs\loga.txt",
              "C:\Users\makker1\Desktop\logs\logb.txt",
              "C:\Users\makker1\Desktop\logs\logc.txt" ]

class LogFile:
    def __init__(self,filepath):
        self.logfile = open(filepath, "r")
        self.head = None

    def __str__(self):
        return "x=" + str(self.x) + "y="+str(self.y)

    def readline (self):
        if self.head != None:
            self.head = self.logfile.readline()

    def previewline (self):
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = self.logfile.readline()

    def close (self):
        self.logfile.close()



logs = map(LogFile(self,filepath).__init__(), lognames)
heads = map(lambda log: None, logs)


>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\makker1\Desktop\mergesort-final.py", line 30, in <module>
    logs = map(LogFile(self,filepath).__init__, lognames)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
>>>
```

If any more info is needed, please let me know. I realize that there are tons of posts about this very problem and have sorted through many of them with no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to call `__init__` explicitly.  Try:

```
logs = map(LogFile, lognames)
```

Sometimes it helps to think of a class as being *callable*.  You can think of a class as something like the following:

```
def LogFile(filepath):
    class _LogFile:
        def __init__(self, path):
            ...
    return _LogFile(filepath)
```

Basically, a class can be thought of as something that you call to create an object instance.  This isn't really true, but in many cases it will appear to be.

Comment: And if you do want to use `__init__` explicitly in a `map()`, you need to leave the parens off; you need to pass a *function reference* to `map()`, not call the function and pass the result of the call to `map()`.

Comment: Oh this is groundbreaking. This language is so nit-picky, I'm having trouble keeping  track of the formalities. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Raj - the comment about a `class` being a function does not hold much beyond this case.  I just found it to be a useful way to think about instance creation.  Happy Python'ing.

Comment: Python is not actually that nit-picky.  The rule is simple: if you use the name of the function, you get a reference to the function; if you put parens after the name, you call the function.  That's equally true any "callalble" object in Python: the bare name gives you the reference, and when you put parens on it you get a call.

Comment: @steveha I've never looked at it so straightforward-ly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a list comprehension answer.  I like this better than `map()`.

```
logs = [LogFile(fname) for fname in lognames]
```